# Perl regex replacement in file skips newlines

Tags: regex, perl

I am currently trying to format text for use with pandoc, but my regex replacement isn't working.
Here is my code so far:

````
#Importing the file
my $filename = 'example.md';
my $file = path($filename);
my $data = $file ->slurp_utf8;

#Placing code blocks into an array and replacing them in the file
my @code_block_values;
my $i = 0;
while($i > 50) {
    @code_bock_values[$i] = ($data =~ /\n\t*```[^`]+(```){1}\n/);
    $data =~ s/\n\t*```[^`]+(```){1}\n/(code_block)/;
    $i = $i + 1;
}

#Replacing the code blocks
$i = 0;
while($i < 50) {
    $data =~ s/\(code_block\)/$code_block_values[$i]/;
    $i = $i + 1;
}
print $data;

$file->spew_utf8( $data );
````

I realize that this probably isn't the most efficient way to be doing this, but right now I'm just trying to get it working.

Basically, I am using github-flavored markdown for typing up my notes, and then trying to convert it with pandoc to a pdf file. I am doing some other formatting before-hand, but I have to extract the code blocks first (which are deliniated by triple backticks (```).)

The following is a sample code block that would be a code block:

````
```bash
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter a number"
read count
if [ $count -eq 100 ]
then
  echo "Example-3: Count is 100"
elif [ $count -gt 100 ]
then
  echo "Example-3: Count is greater than 100"
else
  echo "Example-3: Count is less than 100"
fi
```
````

As far as I can tell, the regex is capturing everything that I need (as tested by an online regex tester), but Perl is only inserting newlines at certain points, specifically newlines followed by a tab.

The previous example translates to:

````
```bash #!/bin/bash echo "Enter a number" read count if [ $count -eq 100 ] then
  echo "Example-3: Count is 100" elif [ $count -gt 100 ] then
  echo "Example-3: Count is greater than 100" else
  echo "Example-3: Count is less than 100" fi
```
````

As you can see, the tabs are also completely removed. I copied over all of the file contents from atom and the different lengths of tabs are as copied over from the editor (not sure that makes a difference.) I did my editing for the shell script in vim but the editing for the notes in atom itself.

I am new to Perl, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The first `while` loop seems to never run, since `$i = 0` it cannot be greater than 50

Comment: What is the purpose of the part of the regex ``(```){1}`` ? Why not just use ``` ? and `@code_bock_values[$i]` should be surrounded be parenthesis in order to capture any capture group

Comment: Sorry I missed the `@` sign in front of `@code_bock_values[$i]`.. maybe that is a typo? It seems more reasonable that is shold be a `$`

Comment: What system are you working on?

Comment: None of this works or even runs without errors (use strict; use warnings;). From the face of it looks like you are just trying to strip out the delimiters ``` Show your input and expected output, or add more examples of what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm new to Perl so I probably haven't been using the best practices/syntax. I'm at work right now, but I will post what I eventually used when I get home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess:

````
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

# Slurps DATA after __END__ into a scalar
my $data = do { local $/; <DATA> };

my @code_block_values;

# Extract and replace code blocks with '(code_block)'
while ($data =~ s/ (``` .*? ```) /(code_block)/xs) {
    push @code_block_values, $1;
}

printf "\n--| Replaced:\n%s", $data;

# Restore '(code_block)' with actual content
$data =~ s/ \(code_block\) / shift @code_block_values /xge;

printf "\n--| Restored:\n%s", $data;

__END__

```bash
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter a number"
read count
if [ $count -eq 100 ]
then
  echo "Example-3: Count is 100"
elif [ $count -gt 100 ]
then
  echo "Example-3: Count is greater than 100"
else
  echo "Example-3: Count is less than 100"
fi
```

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "Hello World\n";
```
````

Output:

````
--| Replaced:

(code_block)

(code_block)

--| Restored:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter a number"
read count
if [ $count -eq 100 ]
then
  echo "Example-3: Count is 100"
elif [ $count -gt 100 ]
then
  echo "Example-3: Count is greater than 100"
else
  echo "Example-3: Count is less than 100"
fi
```

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "Hello World\n";
```
````

If you want to learn more about Perl's regular expressions, [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) and [perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) is a good read.